# The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid. .Net Framework Data Type: Double Error Message: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: sql-server

I have attached the database I created in MSSQL 2016 to MSSQL 2019. The following error appears when changing float data type values. I noticed that in this version of MSSql, instead of the point character I must use the / character.
[image]
[image]

What is the problem? And how can it be solved?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. Numbers are binary values, they have no format. The pictures don't show otherwise. Formats are only used when *applications* convert the text users type into numbers. They do that either using the user's locale or a hard-coded locale. That doesn't mean the database uses any format.

Comment: The pictures you posted are from SSMS, not SQL Server. SSMS is a standalone  DBA tool, not a general purpose data entry application. The latest version is 19.3. It's possible that at some point a decision was made to use the user's locale for data entry instead of the US format. This has nothing to do with the database and will behave the same whether you target SQL Server 2016, 2019, 2022 or any other

Comment: Probably just another bug in that broken table designer that noone uses. Just write it out in TSQL.

Comment: A bug that started as a feature - making data entry localized sounds nice except all DBAs already use the US format. I'll double down on `noone uses` because that editor actually *locks* the rows with Exclusive locks for as long as the window is open. This will block any other application using the same table. Imagine blocking all the developers using the same dev/test database because you tried to edit a lookup table and forgot to close the window

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I found out that I changed my OS datetime format to local. I reset it to the US and solved it.

Comment: That changes the format for all the applications on your machine. There was no problem in the first place, only an incorrect expectation. There *is* a problem now - when you try to type something into Excel or any other application, or try to work with a CSV using your localized settings,  you'll find all expect US-style numbers now